# How to set bar content to full width

Tags: android

I am using xml layout for my app bar. i have drawer menu on the left. my problem is that the content is only 30% width from the space i have. i cant find a way to open the width to all space i have there. i want to use all the space i have. I am using Navigation drawer activity and i removed the right 3 dot menu (deleted the onCreateOptionMenu), all controllers are set to match parent and stil, not working [image: screen shot from the app]

Comment: are you using linear layout ?

Comment: Please post all of the relevant xml

Comment: @8hubham WOW! i didn't think about that. change to Relative and its working great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
    action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)action.getCustomView().getParent();
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    toolbar.getContentInsetEnd();
    toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```